# Function which takes a string as input and returns an array of strings as follows ABC(abcde) should return [Abcde, aBcde, abCde, abcDe, abcdE]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays, function

I am doing this in this way but its remove string previous characters, its out put is (Magic,Agic,Gic,Ic,C) but I want the whole string to be concate before and after.

```
      public string[] Transform(string st)
 {
     string[] arr = new string[st.Length];

     string[] arr1 = new string[st.Length];
     for (int x = 0; x < st.Length; x++)
     {
         arr1[x] = char.ToLower(st[x]) + "".ToString();
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < st.Length; i++)
     {
         string st1 = "";
         {
             st1 = char.ToUpper(st[i]) + st.Substring(i + 1);
         }
         arr[i] = st1; 
     }
         return arr; 

 }
```

Comment: You are creating arr1 as an array and then never referencing it again. That is a clue. The debugger will help locate the other issues.

Comment: arr1  is added wrongly I forget to remove it from code i was testing some other scnerio for that purpose I have create arr1

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single loop:

```
public static string[] Transform(string str)
{
    var strs = new List<string>();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Clear();
        sb.Append(str);
        sb[i] = char.ToUpper(str[i]);
        strs.Add(sb.ToString());
    }
    return strs.ToArray();
}
```

What this does is adds the `str` to a `StringBuilder` and then modifies the indexed character with the upper case version of that character. For example, the input `abcde` will give:

```
Abcde
aBcde
abCde
abcDe
abcdE
```

[Try it out on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/acZC45)

If you wanted to get really fancy I'm sure there is some convoluted LINQ that can do the same, but this gives you a basic framework for how it can work.

Comment: It is unnecessary and a bit inefficient to construct and fill a `List<string>` first if you know the exact result length and are planning to return an array.

Comment: Thank you Ron Beyer it really helps and its solve my issue.

Comment: @RuudKobes The only thing is to set the length of the list when it is constructed, but a `List` isn't really inefficient compared to an array in this case, and it uses an array as a backing store anyway. You could put an array there but we aren't talking memory savings or much on the processing side.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add left part of the string. Try to do like this:

st1 = **st.ToLower().Substring +** char.ToUpper(st[i]) + st.Substring(i + 1);

Comment: Sorry. I forgot about "0".
This is right answer:

If (i=0)
st1 = char.ToUpper(st[i]) + st.Substring(i + 1);
else
st1 = st.ToLower().Substring(i-1) + char.ToUpper(st[i]) + st.Substring(i + 1);

Comment: You should edit your answer to include updated code instead of posting it in a comment.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank you, will use your recomendation next time!
Its just "First blood" :)

Answer (score 0):

1. I wrote an answer for your questions (it's second code snippet), you can modify it for your needs, like changing the return type to string[], or use ToArray() extension method if you wanna stick with it. I think it's more readable this way.

I decided to put a the end little profiler to check CPU usage and memory compared to @Ron Beyer answer.

*Here is my first attempt:*

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = Transform("abcde");
        result.ToList().ForEach(WriteLine);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> Transform(string str)
    {
        foreach (var w in str)
        {
            var split = str.Split(w);

            yield return  split[0] + char.ToUpper(w) + split[1];
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
    Abcde
    aBcde
    abCde
    abcDe
    abcdE
```

*Code fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/gnsAGX*

There is one huge drawback of that code above, it works only if the passed word has unique letters. Therefore "aaaaa" won't produce proper result.

2. Here is my second successful attempt that seems works with any string input. I used one instance of StringBuilder to decrease the number of objects that would need to be created and manage on one instance, instead of so much copying objects so it's more optimized.

   ```
   public static void Main()
   {
       var result = Transform("aaaaa");
       result.ToList().ForEach(WriteLine);
   }

   public static IEnumerable<string> Transform(string str)
   {
       var result = new StringBuilder(str.ToLower()); 
       for( int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
       { 
           result[i] = char.ToUpper(str[i]);
           yield return result.ToString();
           result[i] = char.ToLower(str[i]);
       }
   }
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   Aaaaa
   aAaaa
   aaAaa
   aaaAa
   aaaaA
   ```

   *Code fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tzhXtP*
3. Measuring execute time and memory uses.

   I will use dotnetfiddle.net status panel, to make it easier.
   Fiddle has few limitations like time execution of code 10 sec and used memory
   besides differences are very significant.
   I tested programs with 14 000 repetitions, my code additionally changes the output to array[].

   - My answer (https://dotnetfiddle.net/1fLVw9)

     ```
     Last Run:   12:23:09 pm
     Compile:    0.046s
     Execute:    7.563s
     Memory: 16.22Gb
     CPU:    7.609s
     ```
   - Compared answer (https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zc88F2)

     ```
     Compile:    0.031s
     Execute:    9.953s
     Memory: 16.22Gb
     CPU:    9.938s
     ```

It slightly reduces the execution time.
  Hope this helps!

Comment: Your benchmark is misleading and simply incorrect, because your alternative is only declaring a **specification** of the outcome, by defining an IEnumerable. You'll need to actually enumerate the result to get a somewhat comparable result. If you also reduce the string length to a reasonable size, there is just a minor improvement. Whether the IEnumerable really helps depends on the usage, but OP is specifically asking for an array.

Comment: @RuudKobes That's true about IEnumerable thanks, I fixed it. I can agree about minor improvement. Finally, for 14000 rep it takes 2.39 sec. faster, but memory surprisingly for me stays the same. My goal was to create the least number of objects and code the easiest to understand. 
The more efficient way has written by Jim Berg, its similar to my, but operate on simplest types. Good to keep in mind that less is not always the quicker, but sometimes it isn't the most important.

Comment: Indeed. However, your benchmark result is still influenced by the very long string you are using. If you use a single iteration of that  "qwerty..." string your solution will actually be slower than the one you are comparing to

Answer (score 0):

Here.  This is twice as fast as the method that uses a string builder and a List

```
public static string[] Transform(string str)
{
    var strs = new string [str.Length];
    var sb = str.ToCharArray();

    char oldCh;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        oldCh = sb[i];
        sb[i] = char.ToUpper(sb[i]);
        strs[i] = new string (sb);
        sb[i] = oldCh;
    }
    return strs;
}
```

There's no need to clear and keep reading the string to the string builder.    We also know the size of the array so that can be allocated at the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string[] Transform(string str)
{
    var strs = new string [str.Length];
    var sb = str.ToCharArray();

    char oldCh;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        oldCh = sb[i];
        sb[i] = char.ToUpper(sb[i]);
        strs[i] = new string (sb);
        sb[i] = oldCh;
    }
    return strs;
}
```

Comment: answered by Jim berg is a right and efficient answer of my post

Comment: To indicate that, you can accept that answer by clicking the green check mark to the left of the answer.